# Reacting Grignard reagent with amides

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent, amides

> Propene in the presence of $\ce{HBr}$ and $\ce{H2O2}$ gives **A**.
> **A** on reaction with $\ce{Mg}$ in dry ether gives **B**.
> **B** on reaction with acetamide, $\ce{CH3C(O)NH2}$, gives **C**.

In the above question, I got **A** as 1-bromopropane and **B** as propylmagnesium bromide. As for **C**, I got

$$\ce { CH3-CH2-CH3 + CH3C(=O)NHMgBr}$$

The ratio of moles of the Grignard reagent *vs.* acetamide is not specified. Should I add an additional propyl Grignard and arrive at $\ce{CH3-CH2-CH3}$, $\ce{CH4}$, and $\ce{ CH3C(OH)N(MgBr)2}$ ?

I need help with figuring out the product in the reaction of **B** and acetamide.

Comment: The pKa of acetamide is ~25 - easily acidic enough to be deprotonated by Grignard, and that is where the reaction stops in my opimion.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21931/do-grignard-reagents-react-with-amides https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88361/leaving-group-stability-when-treated-with-grignard

Answer (score 2):

In the reaction that you have mentioned above, the reaction essentially stops after the reaction has taken place in a 1:1 ratio. That is because the electrophilicity of the polar bond of the acid derivative has reduced sharply so it cannot undergo further reaction.

However, had the nucleophile been $\ce{RLi}$ instead of $\ce{RMgX}$ ($\ce{RLi}$ is more ionic and hence a better nucleophile), further reaction would've been possible, although it provides the product in low yield. R attacks C=O resulting in the formation of $\ce{R-C-O- Li+}$ (The other groups remain as they were- the only difference being that it is $\ce{NHLi}$ instead of $\ce{NHMgX}$)

Comment: [Here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) is information on how you can format (no coding involved!) your answer.